# How to update recyclerview in the second tab in viewpager from first tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

One of the problems I am currently facing is that if a user adds something to their timetable, it should be refreshed in the `recyclerview` in the second tab `Current Timetable`. However, it never updates and the user has to go back to the main menu, back onto the `Timetables` activity and then select `Current Timetable`. I believe it is something to do with my `ViewPager` and its adapter. I just can't see where I am going wrong and I am sure it is something simple that I am missing. Please could you modify my code such that it will work

Here is my code:
The viewpager class

```
public class Timetables extends AppCompatActivity{
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timetables);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TimetablesAdapter timetablesAdapter = new TimetablesAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Timetables.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(timetablesAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The fragmentpageradapter class:

```
public class TimestableAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    String tabNames[] = new String[] {"All timetables", "Current Timetable", "Expired"};
    Context context;

    public TimestableAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new AllTimetables();
            case 1:
                return new CurrentTimetables();
            case 2:
                return new ExpiredTimetables();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabNames[position];
    }
}
```

This is the `CurrentTimetable` class:

```
public class CurrentTimetables extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static MusicRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Timetables> list;

    public CurrentTimetables(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currenttimetable, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timetablerecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list = new ArrayList<Timetables>();
        adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list, CurrentTimetables.this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabBackground = new TabBackground(CurrentTimetables.this, list, spinnerItems, adapter, spinnerAdapter);
        tabBackground.populateConditionsList();
        inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        populate();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void populate(){
        String dbURL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(fragment.getActivity());
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (dbURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        if(!list.isEmpty()){
                            list.clear();
                        }
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int timetableID = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("timetableID"));
                                String timetableName = jsonObject.getString("timetableName");
                                String subjectName = jsonObject.getString("subjectName");

                                Timetables timetables = new Timetables(timetableID, timetableName, subjectName);
                                list.add(timetables);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                }
                );
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
 }
```

Would really mean a lot of someone could help me out

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code for your CurrentTimetables Fragment class

Comment: if you have database for timetable, try to refresh recyclerview in onResume method of currentTimetable fragment.

Comment: Oh ok, do you mean call the populate method (this populates the recyclerview with the values from the db) in onResume?

Comment: It doesnt work, I put it in `onResume()` - still no luck

Comment: In Tabs all fragments will be called as once so it's oncreateview and onviewcreated method will be called when you will switch fragments its onResume method will be called. You should check its life cycle to know about it.

Comment: @VarunKumar I have updated the post to include the `CurrentTimetable` class. @Dhaval - I have included the  `CurrentTimetable` class - could you please tell me where I have gone wrong

Comment: You are calling web api and check when you get data you didnt add it to adapter and called notifydatasetchanged. try adding or calling adapter constructor and `recyclerview.setadapter` after getting data from volley.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I believe it is the viewpager. I give up now!!!

Comment: Nothing wrong with the web api - when I come out of the viewpager and back in and click on `Current Timetables` tab - it works

Comment: I will answer question and you can try that. It is little bit typical to explain everything on comments.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just think its something to do with the viewpager

Answer (score 3):

There are some changes needed in your code. If you check Fragment's [LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png) you will understand how it works with Tabular View.

Check out Code I have made from above code.

```
public class CurrentTimetables extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static MusicRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Timetables> list;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.currenttimetable, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.timetablerecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        tabBackground = new TabBackground(CurrentTimetables.this, list, spinnerItems, adapter, spinnerAdapter);
        tabBackground.populateConditionsList();
        // If you have another Component add here using finViewById() and also you can do
        // other process here. I just used setUserVisibleHint because it will execute when
        // fragment will be visible to user and it will stop over calling to web service.
        /**
         * Populate Recyclerview data if setUserVisibleHint do not work.
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            populate();
        }
    }

    public void populate() {
        String dbURL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(dbURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    list.clear();
                }
                try {
                    list = new ArrayList<Timetables>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        int timetableID = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("timetableID"));
                        String timetableName = jsonObject.getString("timetableName");
                        String subjectName = jsonObject.getString("subjectName");

                        Timetables timetables = new Timetables(timetableID, timetableName, subjectName);
                        list.add(timetables);
                        adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list, context);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });
        jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5 * 1000, 1, 1.0F));
        jsonArrayRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populate();
    }
}
```

I might have forgot something from your code and you might have to add it.

Comment: You know what mate. I don't know how to possibly thank you. IT WORKS!!! The next tab updates but it is delayed by 2 seconds but hey, that is due to the server - I think I can fix that

Comment: Just out of interest what does `jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5 * 1000, 1, 1.0F));` and `jsonArrayRequest.setShouldCache(false);` mean? I never had that but what does it mean?

Comment: RetryPolicy is used to make web service call again and again, first parameter is minTime to continue webservice call , second parameter is number of time it should retry if it fails and third parameter is backoff multiplier.

Comment: really helpful answer..saved my day..+1

Comment: I would not use this approach now because `setUserVisibleHint` seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an interface in mainActivity. Reference it in your fragments. Its is the best way to communicate from one fragment to another. Please refer the link below.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Have a look and if any doubts am here to help.